# NameErrorが出る

Tags: python

以下のコードを実行したいのですがエラーが出てしまいます。
解決方法を教えていただけると幸いです。
元のコードは[data-science-from-scratch/nearest_neighbors.py](https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch/blob/master/code/nearest_neighbors.py)にあります。
現在Pythonを学び始めたばかりなのですが、したいこととしてはk近傍方でk=1,3,5,7でどのような結果になるのか示したいと認識しています。

```
import math

def knn_classify(k, labeled_points, new_point):
    """each labeled point should be a pair (point, label)"""
    # order the labeled points from nearest to farthest
    by_distance = sorted(labeled_points,
                         key=lambda point_label: distance(point_label, new_point))
    # find the labels for the k closest
    k_nearest_labels = [label for _, label in by_distance[:k]]
    return majority_vote(k_nearest_labels)

cities = [(-86.75,33.5666666666667,'Python'),(-88.25,30.6833333333333,'Python'),(-112.016666666667,33.4333333333333,'Java')]
cities = [([longitude, latitude], language) for longitude, latitude, language in cities]

for k in [1,3,5,7]:
    num_correct = 0    
    for city in cities:
        location,actual_language = city
        other_cities = [other_city for other_city in cities
                        if other_city != city]
        predicted_language = knn_classify(k, other_cities, location) 
        if predicted_language == actual_language:
            num_correct += 1
    print (k, "neighbor[s]", num_correct, "correct out of", len(cities) )
```

上記のコードを実行した時に以下のようにエラーが表示されてしまいます。

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-1bab7195f6b1> in <module>()
     26                         if other_city != city]
     27 
---> 28         predicted_language = knn_classify(k, other_cities, location)
     29 
     30         if predicted_language == actual_language:

<ipython-input-32-1bab7195f6b1> in knn_classify(k, labeled_points, new_point)
      6     # order the labeled points from nearest to farthest
      7     by_distance = sorted(labeled_points,
----> 8                          key=lambda point_label: distance(point_label, new_point))
      9 
     10     # find the labels for the k closest

<ipython-input-32-1bab7195f6b1> in <lambda>(point_label)
      6     # order the labeled points from nearest to farthest
      7     by_distance = sorted(labeled_points,
----> 8                          key=lambda point_label: distance(point_label, new_point))
      9 
     10     # find the labels for the k closest

NameError: name 'distance' is not defined
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！ エラーが出てしまってコードが動かないときは、どういうエラーが出たのかもコピペしてください。さもないと今どういう問題が起こっているのかがさっぱり分かりません。また、できれば[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)を載せてください。どうしてもコードが長すぎる場合は、今回のように大事なところを引用した上で、ソース全体へのリンクがあると嬉しいです。ただし他人のコード丸写しは時にライセンス違反になる可能性があるのでご注意ください。ご自分の質問は質問の下の「編集」から自由に書き換えられますので、お試しください。

Answer (score 2):

python は詳しくないのですが…

`distance` メソッドは

```
from linear_algebra import distance
```

ここで宣言されているように、`linear_algebra.py` が必要です。
(で、`linear_algebra.py` を読み込もうとすると、また他のものが芋づる式に必要になってくるのでしょうけど)

また、`majority_vote` メソッドも不足しているようですね。
これは元のコード `nearest_neighbors.py` に含まれていますね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
majority_voteは書き忘れていました。liner_algebra.pyに関しては検索したのですがインストールができず、、という感じです。

Comment: @aaa [data-science-from-scratch/README.md](https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch/blob/master/README.md) を読めば分かるかと思いますが、`linear_algebra.py` は同じディレクトリにあります。